# Ms Word 12.0 Class Library

Tags: com, model

1. Where to get the 
   list of dlls present in microsoft word 12.0 .
2. Can we download microsoft word 12.0 Component seperately and install it in the client system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such list.  You can have a look-see in the install directory, but you won't get them all because Word uses COM servers heavily.  Attaching a debugger and looking in the Modules window gets you merely a snapshot of what DLLs happened to be loaded at that particular point in time.  There is no download available for Word components, your customer will have to purchase a retail license.